# Clear floats without using a container

Tags: html, css, css-float

I've got the following grid:

http://jsfiddle.net/LPrwP/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <article class="col33"></article>
</div>
```

Each article is floated left and has 33% width, and appears like so:

```
[col][col][col]
[col][col][col]
[col][col][col]
```

However, sometimes a column has a larger height and breaks the float completely, rendering it like this:

```
 [col][col][col]
 [col][col]
 [col]
 [col][col][col]
```

To prevent this, I usually wrap each 3 in a wrapper, like so:

```
[row][col][col][col][/row]
[row][col][col][col][/row]
[row][col][col][col][/row]
```

This stops it breaking when content gets the column's height is different. This is the kind of solution I would like to emulate.

However, I cannot wrap each 3, because I'm also loading more posts with AJAX (infinite scroll). This can break it if the amount of columns are not divisible by 3:

```
[row][col][col][col][/row]
[row][col][col][col][/row]
[row][col][/row] //this was left over

//loaded content
[row][col][col][col][/row]
[row][col][col][col][/row]
```

To try and combat this, I'm going to rely soley on CSS fix this. I'm trying this solution, but it does not work:

```
.col33:nth-child(3n):after {
content: '.';
clear: both;
}
```

**Does anyone know how to clear floats by using just CSS and without clearing the container?**

Comment: [**Clearfix 'hack' - via CSS-Tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Comment: Is that not requiring me to wrap every 3 in a group / row, though?

Answer (score 0):

I usualy add  after every 3 items. I don't think there is only CSS solution:

```
<div class="container">
    <article class="col33 h60"></article>
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <article class="col33 h60"></article>
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <article class="col33 h60"></article>
    <article class="col33"></article>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <article class="col33"></article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the sollution you want is to clear floats with `nth-child`

```
.col33:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPrwP/2/)

Tell me if that suits you.

Comment: Thanks but it's not quite what I'm after. I was hoping for something like @user3774355 's solution, but without having to add HTML after every 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Instead of using floats, I can use `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: top` to achieve the same effect. Here is the CSS that fixed it:

```
.col33 {
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    padding: 15px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

The only bad thing is the unncessary white space that it creates, which I dealt with my reducing the width to `33%` rather than `33.3%` and making the parent's `font-size: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

add this css

```
.container {
width: 500px;
background-color: blue;
overflow: hidden;


}
.col33 {
width: 31%;
height: 40px;
background-color: red;
float: left;
margin-left: 1px;
margin-top: 3px;
margin-right: 1px;
}
.h60 {
height: 60px;
}
.col33:nth-child(3n+1){
background-color: orange;
clear: both;
}

.col33:nth-child(3n):after {
content: '.';
clear: both;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maulikshekhada/LPrwP/12/)